# Assigning a value of a variable to json object instead of a variable

Tags: python, json

I have a json object and a json array as such:

```
data = {
    'var1': [1],
    'var2': [2]
}
data_final = [
    {
        'name': 'name1',
        'properties': data
    },
    {
        'name': 'name2',
        'properties': data
    }
]
```

When I append something to 'var2' in 'properties' of 'name2' object, I append it as well to 'var2' in 'properties' of 'name1'. I find that if I convert the Json array to string and back into Json array it works just fine and appends only to 'name2's 'var2':

```
data_final_temp = json.dumps(data_final)
data_final = json.loads(data_final_temp)
data_final[1]['properties']['var2'].append(3)
```

Such method seems like a workaround rather than a solution - is there any way to assign only values of 'data' Json object rather than assign it as a variable?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the current and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any way to assign only values of 'data' Json object rather than assign it as a variable?

Yes, you can create a deep copy of the object using [`copy.deepcopy`](https://docs.python.org/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy).

```
import copy

data = {
    'var1': [1],
    'var2': [2]
}

data_final = [
    {
        'name': 'name1',
        'properties': copy.deepcopy(data)
    },
    {
        'name': 'name2',
        'properties': copy.deepcopy(data)
    }
]
```